# Optional conversion of basic types in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to support an abstraction of an ID type for a framework.  Example here:

```
object AmINecessary {
  case class StringConverter[T](op: String => T)
  implicit val toInt = new StringConverter[Int](_.toInt)
  implicit val toLong = new StringConverter[Long](_.toLong)
}

class Foo[ID] {
  // ID can be String, Long, or Int
  import AmINecessary._
  // If ID is string, return string, otherwise convert to ID
  def getID(id: String)(implicit c: StringConverter[ID] = null): ID = if (c == null) id.asInstanceOf[ID] else c.op(id)
}
```

This is then used as:

```
val fooString = new Foo[String]
val fooLong = new Foo[Long]
val fooInt = new Foo[Int]


fooString.getID("asdf") // "asdf":String
fooLong.getID("1234") // 1234:Long
fooInt.getID("1234") // 1234:Int
fooInt.getID("asdf") // java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

This works as expected.  My questions are:

1. using an optional implicit by defaulting it to null then branching on it feels *bad*.  What is the scala way to accomplish that?
2. Is it really necessary to write implicit conversions for a string to long or int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option would be to simply add an implicit `StringConverter[String]` and remove the default `null` value.
That way your `fooString` works without risking a `ClassCastException` for every other type.

```
object AmINecessary {
  case class StringConverter[T](op: String => T)
  implicit val toInt = new StringConverter[Int](_.toInt)
  implicit val toLong = new StringConverter[Long](_.toLong)
  implicit val idConverter = new StringConverter[String](identity)
}

class Foo[ID] {
  import AmINecessary.StringConverter

  def getID(id: String)(implicit c: StringConverter[ID]): ID = c.op(id)
}
```

Regarding your question 2, the type class approach is not *really* necessary (but note that there are no *implicit conversions* here). You can also do it like this:

```
abstract class Foo[ID] {
  def getID(id: String): ID
}

class FooInt extends Foo[Int] {
  def getID(id: String) = id.toInt
}

class FooLong extends Foo[Long] {
  def getID(id: String) = id.toLong
}

class FooString extends Foo[String] {
  def getID(id: String) = id
}
```

Comment: The second example is what I ended up doing after fighting with the implicits.  Doesn't feel great, but better than implicit mess and works.

Answer (score 0):

1) About implicit defaulting to null, you could just:

```
object Unsafe {
  implicit val toT[T] = new StringConverter[T](_.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

2) It doesn't seem as a good idea. First, because you're hiding asInstanceOf, which is unsafe operation (potential runtime exception). Second, the more explicit conversion is - the better.

If you expect some complex transformations - it's better to return option from your getID method:

```
def getId[T](id: String)(converter: Option[StringConverter] = None) = converter.map(_.op(id))
```

However, default parameters aren't the best approach either. I'd stick with compile-time error requiring user to either write own converter or explicitly do an `asInstanceOf`, in general.

In your concrete case `asInstanceOf` doesn't make much sense as the only type it would work for is String, like `getId[String]`, so what's the point of calling `getId` then?

Comment: The idea for the null converter: there are only three possible types of ID.  When I tried adding a StringToString it whined about ambiguous resolution.  For some reason, Jasper-M's version works, not sure why my original attempt did not.